# how to convert image to tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

*I have data and generate it with image data generator ,how to convert image data generator to tensor*
`

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    brightness_range=[0.2,1.0],
    horizontal_flip=True)`
```

```
`train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,target_size=(224,224),
                                                    batch_size = batch_size,class_mode = 'binary')`
```

```
`train = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_generator, dtype=tf.float32)`
```

when trying the code above 'convert to tensor' it gives me error but doesn't specify the error

```
`train = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_generator, dtype=tf.float32)`
```

when trying the code above 'convert to tensor' it gives me error but doesn't specify the error, and the colab craches "i do the code in google colab"
my question how to convert image from image data generator to tensor

after answering me for img_batch , next:

i tried this code to extract the image, then convert it to tensor and then stacked it, is it right? for extraxt all image from the generator:

```
img_test, batch_label = next(test_generator)
for i in range(int(test_generator.n/batch_size)-1):
  img2, batch_label = next(test_generator)
  print(type(img2)) # is numpy array
  img_test = np.append(img_test,img2,axis = 0)
  print(type(img_test))
  for img_t in img_test:
  img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img_t, dtype=tf.float32)
  img_st = tf.stack(img)
```

Comment: What's the underlying issue? It sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this generator has a "registered Tensor conversion" function as it is stated in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)

This is more likely intended to convert *data* not *data generators*!

So I suggest that you generate a batch of data and put this batch into the function.

Depending on what you are doing, you might not even need to do the conversion yourself but it might be handled under the hood

```
gen = ...

batch_imgs, batch_labels = next(gen)

type(batch_imgs)  # is numpy array

tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_imgs, dtype=tf.float32)  # this works since it uses the image batch not the generator object
```

Comment: it works, but i think it store the last image, or some of images , i want to transfer the all images in directory , I tried for loop or enumrate and  save it in listppend doesnt work